# How to install complete Ruby on Rails environment in Ubuntu 12.10 that already have XAMPP installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu

I have XAMPP (Apache + MySQL + PHP) installed on my computer and I wish to begin using RoR and possibly keep XAMPP. Is there any way to use both in one computer?

I have many questions about Ruby on Rails:

- What is the equivalent to Apache to use RoR?
- Is there any package with all I need just like XAMPP, for RoR?
- RoR comes with Coffeescript and SASS/SCSS?
- Is it possible to use SQL/MySQL with RoR and also what's the best database for Ruby?
- What's the best/simplest way to install RoR in Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: Rails can co-exist with Apache, just set the port used by Rails to something besides what your Apache is using, or use something like Passenger. Otherwise, you are asking too many questions to make a concise answer. From [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent to Apache for RoR is ... apache!  In development, most of us use webrick which you run with the `rails server` command (or `rails s` for short) from the root of your project, then access from a browser with "http://localhost:3000".  If you wish to use your existing XAMPP version of Apache, you'll need to configure it to listen on some other port than your PHP app.

You can use your existing MySQL installation.  Or if you're just getting started, a default rails app starts out with SQLLite, which is a simple, file-based RDBMS that's fine for a while to get going.  You can use MySQL, but it will require a little configuration in your `database.yml` file.  "Best" database is probably MySQL because that's what most people use; I personally have a strong preference for PostgreSQL, but it's just because it's a far better database :-).

RoR 3.x supports CoffeeScript and SASS; ruby gems install the needed binaries to compile both into JS and CSS respectively.

The "best/simplest" installation on Ubuntu is to follow the few steps here: http://rubyonrails.org/download:

- install ruby if not already installed (`apt-get install ruby1.9.3`)
- install rubygems if not already installed (`apt-get install rubygems`)
- install rails `gem install rails`

Comment: I wouldn't say using apt-get is the 'best' way to install ruby. RVM would be a better way to install it.

Comment: Perhaps, but I would still argue apt-get is simplest, especially if you assume ubuntu is being used for the production server.  I have run in environments with RVM on production, but there aren't really that many cases where you're changing ruby versions (other than doing security updates) in production.  So if we're talking about keeping things simple, RVM doesn't necessarily do that -- I am a huge fan of RVM for what it does, but it's not "simplest" :-).  Just sayin'

Comment: Even if apt is simpler, apt doesn't tend to play well with gems. Also  In ubuntu, Ruby is split into many packages, so you'd have to do like 'apt get install ruby ruby-full rubygems' -- because ruby-full comes with 'irb' but not ruby gems. I personally would compile from source before ever using apt to install ruby on Ubuntu. There will also come a time when you may want to upgrade it and versions will matter too.

Comment: apt-get install ruby1.9.3 is not advised on Ubuntu Server as it installs the X11 packages.

Comment: Shouldn't i do `gem1.9.3 install rails` to be sure rails is installed in ruby 1.9 and not in ruby 1.8?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use https://rvm.io/, especially when getting started. (There are other options.)

There is no "best DB for Ruby", but MySql and PostgreSql are popular for obvious reasons.

Rails can be self-hosting using webrick, or you can hook it up to a real server, or use Thin, or... But for getting starting, IMO normal `rails s` running webrick is fine.

Once you've installed Rails and installed the required bundles, CS/SASS/etc. are all there.

Most tutorials include getting started, have you considered just doing something like that, like http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ or similar?